# tables in the middle of the page

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have 3 tables in my article. I want table 1 in the middle of page 1, table 2 in the middle of page 2 and table 3 in the middle of page 3.
I tried :

```
    \begin{filecontents*}{example.eps}
\end{filecontents*}
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{svjour3} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[nottoc, notlof, notlot]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}  % ps2pdf car je compile via Latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,                          
    linkcolor=blue, % Couleur des liens internes
    citecolor=red, % Couleur des numéros de la biblio dans le corps
    urlcolor=blue  } % Couleur des url
%\usepackage[hyperpageref]{backref}  % pour retourner à la citation à partir de la biblio
\usepackage{natbib} % pour changer la couleur des numéros dans la biblio
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[p]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
$|C|$   &   $|T|$   &   $\sum_{c\in C}R_c$  &   $\sum_{c\in C} |T_c|R_c$    &   $\sum_{t\in T}N_t$  &   $E$ &   $\frac{\sum_{t\in T}N_t}{\sum_{c\in C}R_c}$ &   $\max_{c\in C}\frac{W_c}{R_c}$  &   $Z$ \\  \hline
1   &   5   &   7   &   35  &   1   &   5   &   0,14    &   0,14    &   0,03    \\  
1   &   5   &   10  &   50  &   3   &   5   &   0,30    &   0,30    &   0,06    \\  
1   &   5   &   10  &   50  &   8   &   5   &   0,80    &   0,80    &   0,16    \\  
1   &   5   &   10  &   50  &   3   &   5   &   0,30    &   0,30    &   0,06    \\  
1   &   5   &   10  &   50  &   8   &   5   &   0,80    &   0,80    &   0,16    \\  
1   &   5   &   7   &   35  &   1   &   5   &   0,14    &   0,14    &   0,03    \\  
1   &   5   &   10  &   50  &   13  &   2   &   1,30    &   1,30    &   0,26    \\  
1   &   5   &   10  &   50  &   6   &   5   &   0,60    &   0,60    &   0,12    \\  
1   &   5   &   7   &   35  &   3   &   5   &   0,43    &   0,43    &   0,09    \\  
1   &   5   &   10  &   50  &   2   &   5   &   0,20    &   0,20    &   0,04    \\  
1   &   5   &   10  &   50  &   5   &   5   &   0,50    &   0,50    &   0,10    \\  
1   &   5   &   10  &   50  &   3   &   5   &   0,30    &   0,30    &   0,06    \\  
1   &   5   &   10  &   50  &   5   &   5   &   0,50    &   0,50    &   0,10    \\  
1   &   5   &   10  &   50  &   1   &   5   &   0,10    &   0,10    &   0,02    \\  
1   &   5   &   7   &   35  &   2   &   5   &   0,29    &   0,29    &   0,06    \\  
1   &   5   &   10  &   50  &   1   &   5   &   0,10    &   0,10    &   0,02    \\  
1   &   5   &   7   &   35  &   4   &   5   &   0,57    &   0,57    &   0,11    \\  
1   &   5   &   7   &   35  &   2   &   5   &   0,29    &   0,29    &   0,06    \\  
1   &   5   &   10  &   50  &   11  &   1   &   1,10    &   1,10    &   0,22    \\  
1   &   5   &   7   &   35  &   3   &   5   &   0,43    &   0,43    &   0,09    \\  
1   &   5   &   10  &   50  &   4   &   5   &   0,40    &   0,40    &   0,08    \\  
1   &   5   &   7   &   35  &   2   &   5   &   0,29    &   0,29    &   0,06    \\  
1   &   5   &   7   &   35  &   0   &   5   &   0,00    &   0,00    &   0,00    \\  
1   &   5   &   7   &   35  &   0   &   5   &   0,00    &   0,00    &   0,00    \\  
1   &   5   &   7   &   35  &   3   &   5   &   0,43    &   0,43    &   0,09    \\  
1   &   5   &   10  &   50  &   4   &   5   &   0,40    &   0,40    &   0,08    \\  
1   &   5   &   10  &   50  &   6   &   5   &   0,60    &   0,60    &   0,12    \\  
1   &   5   &   7   &   35  &   0   &   5   &   0,00    &   0,00    &   0,00    \\  
1   &   5   &   7   &   35  &   0   &   5   &   0,00    &   0,00    &   0,00    \\  
1   &   5   &   7   &   35  &   0   &   5   &   0,00    &   0,00    &   0,00    \\  
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\textit{Results of S1}}
\label{tab_s1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

But all tables are on the top of each page.
Have you any idea ?
Thank you.

Comment: We need a complete example. The default is to centre them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a deliberate design change by the class.

You could revert it with

```
\documentclass{svjour3}
\makeatletter
\setlength\@fptop{0\p@ \@plus 1fil}
\makeatother
```

Although the usual advice with publisher classes is *not* to change the design, the whole point is to force the publisher design rules (rather than give authors choice)